# Power Automate - Or Condition with multiply Grouped AND statements is always turning true

Tags: forms, power-automate

I have a problem with my power automate flow, that is always turning out true regardless of the input.
The outputs are numbers from inputs from a MS Form, that I compose to floats.
The condition should check the input numbers is between a range of two numbers in all 4 AND statements and if one of the statements is false, the condition should be false and then send a mail. But it is allways turns out true.

[image]

Comment: You are applying OR condition on all 4 expression. If any one is True your overall result would be True. Apply AND on top of all condition. That will fix it

Comment: Your right. It now works perfectly as it should. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Gandalf it now works perfectly and here is the solution.
[image]